# Cassandra test with Jmeter

Tags: java, groovy, jar, cassandra, jmeter

I am not able to run Cassandra with Jmeter.
Following error is shown even after including all the jar files of Cassandra Jmeter plugin:

```
Response message: javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
General error during class generation: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class com.datastax.driver.core.Session due to missing dependency org/apache/cassandra/transport/Message$Request
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is about missing org.apache.cassandra.transport.Message class in JMeter classpath, the class can be found in [cassandra-all.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cassandra/cassandra-all), however you need to choose the right version in order to avoid [Jar Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell)

Looking into [JMeter Cassandra Plugin installation instructions](https://github.com/Netflix/CassJMeter/wiki/Installation-Instruction#copy-the-artifacts-into-the-jmeter-lib-and-libext-directorys) you need to:

1. Build the plugin:

   ```
   mvn dependency:copy-dependencies install -DexcludeGroupIds=org.apache.jmeter
   ```
2. Copy the plugin to JMeter's "lib/ext" folder:

   ```
   cp -Rf ~/CassJMeter/target/CassJMeter-0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar lib/ext/
   ```
3. Copy all the plugin's dependencies to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation:

   ```
   cp -Rf ~/CassJMeter/target/dependency/* lib/
   ```
4. Restart JMeter to pick the .jars up

Make sure that [`cp` command](https://shapeshed.com/unix-cp/) was successful, you can check its status code by running `echo $?` in the terminal, it should return `0`

You may also find following articles useful:

- [Cassandra Load Testing with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/cassandra-load-testing-with-groovy/)
- [JMeter Plugin for Cassandra](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/jmeter-plugin-for-cassandra-8ca848c0d480)